# Menu's are not rendering properly in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Since I am new to react js development, I am developing one react application that have a menu and dashboard components. I want to render the menu based on an user role. The user role where I kept from browser local storage which is set properly.
The menu component is below:

```
import { ReactSession } from 'react-client-session';
import dashboard from './dashboard';
import dashboard1 from './dashboard1';
import dashboard2 from './dashboard2';
import companies from './companies';
import investors from './investors';
import incubators from './incubators';

// ==============================|| MENU ITEMS ||============================== //

ReactSession.setStoreType("localStorage");
let role = ReactSession.get("role");
let menuItems = [];
{
    if (role == 3) {
        menuItems = {
            items: [dashboard1, companies]

        };
    }
    else if (role  == 2) {
        menuItems = {
            items: [dashboard, incubators]

        };
    }
    else if (role == 4) {
        menuItems = {
            items: [dashboard2, investors]

        };
    }
}
export default menuItems;
```

The role variable kept the status 2,3,4 based on user login but the menu items are properly rendered only after manually refresh. How to fix this issue?

Comment: You stated, that you get user role from browser session storage, but in code you use local storage. Also that sentence does not make much sense.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I am using local storage only. Now I am edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code above, please see the following code, it should solve your problem:

```
import { ReactSession } from 'react-client-session';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'; // Import useState and useEffect hooks
import dashboard from './dashboard';
import dashboard1 from './dashboard1';
import dashboard2 from './dashboard2';
import companies from './companies';
import investors from './investors';
import incubators from './incubators';

// ==============================|| MENU ITEMS ||============================== //

ReactSession.setStoreType("localStorage");

const Menu = () => {
    // Initialize state for menu items
    const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState([]);

    // Fetch user role from localStorage
    const role = ReactSession.get("role");

    // Update menu items based on user role
    useEffect(() => {
        let updatedMenuItems = [];
        if (role === 3) {
            updatedMenuItems = [dashboard1, companies];
        } else if (role === 2) {
            updatedMenuItems = [dashboard, incubators];
        } else if (role === 4) {
            updatedMenuItems = [dashboard2, investors];
        }
        // Update state with new menu items
        setMenuItems(updatedMenuItems);
    }, [role]); // Update menu items whenever role changes

    // Render menu items
    return (
        <div>
            {menuItems.map((MenuItem, index) => (
                <MenuItem key={index} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Menu;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you would need [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main), but it is kind of hard to tell, because you did not provide a full code.

Answer (score 0):

wrapt them in a function and  call that function in a useEffect

or wrap the condition in useEffect and depend the useEffect on role value